# Use criterion for statistic driven benchmarking of Substrate pallets

Tags: substrate-node-template, benchmarking, wasm

[Criterion](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs) version 0.4.0 seems to support WASM builds: https://www.tweag.io/blog/2022-03-03-criterion-rs/#first-class-wasm-support

Can we us it to benchmark extrinsics of Substrate pallets?

Comment: I tried to implement it here: https://github.com/achimcc/substrate-arkworks-examples/tree/criterion But the becnhmark results are not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use criterion to benchmark your pallets code. So far we only did this outside of WASM, but now it could be interesting to do inside WASM.

Fundamentally there are two ways to benchmark:

- Using the FRAME macros to benchmark your no-std runtime code which results in a `weights.rs`
- Using something else, like `criterion` to optimize your code. It is currently not possible to use `criterion` to generate weights.

So far we never mixed the two. I'm not sure what your goal is here, but if you just want to optimize your code, you could factor it out into `do_` functions like `do_mul_affine_g2_bls12_377_optimized` and then benchmark that instead. Then you wont need the `new_test_ext` and the storage caching that happens in there. Could be that this messes with your results.
In most cases you don't want them to be calls anyway; for example `mul_projective_ed_on_bls12_381` is an arithmetic function and not a call.

Removing the externalities and directly calling an internal function results in this:

```
mul_affine_g2_bls12_377/mul_affine_g2_bls12_377
                        time:   [1.3610 µs 1.3616 µs 1.3621 µs]
                        change: [-98.790% -98.775% -98.761%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has improved.
Found 1 outliers among 100 measurements (1.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high severe
```

The optimized version still seems a lot slower

Comment: Thanks! I do it here now: https://github.com/achimcc/substrate-arkworks-examples

These are my benchmark results, the most optimized functions are slower: https://github.com/achimcc/substrate-arkworks-examples/blob/gh-pages/BENCHMARKS.md

Do I have to pass extra paramaeters to `cargo criterion` to benchmark for WASM?

Comment: I have not yet use criterion with WASM, no idea…